# Why does SetPrecision drop "unknown" digits if precision requested is Infinity but retain them if it's finite?

Tags: numerics, precision-and-accuracy, arbitrary-precision

I was trying to reset the imprecision record of a number like `` 0.0076022266122755632`1.025 `` by calling `SetPrecision` with second argument of `Infinity`. But then I was very surprised to see the following counterintuitive behavior:

```
SetPrecision[0.0076022266122755632`1.025, 30]
SetPrecision[0.0076022266122755632`1.025, Infinity]
N@%
```

> 0.00760222661227556321733231370352
>
> 1/128
>
> 0.0078125

I.e., when asked to set finite precision, `SetPrecision` just resets the precision marker, but when asked for infinite precision, it rounds the number to remove actual "extra" digits.

Is this inconsistency intended? How is it justified?

Answer (score 3):

The first line just increases the mantissa size, so programmatically there is no need to do anything to the current mantissa bits.

The second line needs to read the mantissa and its more efficient to only read what is necessary according to the precision. The rest aren't rounded to zero, they are ignored.

Both are correct because they are elements of `Interval[0.0076022266122755632´1.025]`, which is the only thing that makes sense to expect.